# Alternative proof of separation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

There is a quite short proof of the following variant of separation theorem:

Let $X$ be a normed space, $V$ convex and closed and $x\notin V$. Then there is a $x^*\in X^*$ so that $x^*(x) < \inf_{v\in V}x^*(v)$.

The proof I know relies on Hahn-Banach. Now I want to proof it in another way using following famous theorem:

Let $1<p<\infty$, $K$ be a closed convex set in $L^p(\mu)$ and $f\in L^p(\mu)$. Then there is a unique $g \in K$ such that $\vert\vert f-g\vert\vert_{L^p(\mu)}=dist(f,K)$.

Is it true that this works?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works.

*Hint:* you know that
$$\|f - g\|_p^p \le \|f - k\|_p^p$$
for all $k \in K$. Now, use $k = (1-t) \, g + t \, v$ for $v \in K$, $t \in (0,1]$ and let $t \searrow 0$.

In the case $p = 2$, you have
$$0\ge\|f-g\|_2^2 - \|f - g + t \, (g-v)\|_2^2
\\=
-2 \, t \, (f-g,g-v) - t^2 \, \|g-v\|^2
$$
Now, dividing by $t$ and $t \searrow 0$ implies
$$
0 \le 2 \, (f - g,g - v)
$$
for all $ v \in K$. Hence,
$(f-g,f) > (f-g,g) \ge (f-g, v)$.

Comment: Fist, thanks a lot for your fast answer, but I do not understand why your hint would help me. Letting $t$ goes to $0$ just gives me equality in your inequality one line above, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course. You had first divide by an appropriate power of $t$. It might be easier to first consider the Hilbert space case $p = 2$.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with "divide by an appropriate power to $t$"?

Comment: You divide the inequality by $t^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$ (depending on $p$). Then, you let $t \to 0$.

Comment: ah I understand, but I don't see to what limit it converge...

Comment: Try the case $p = 2$ first and expand the squares. In fact, you need the derivative of $\mathbb R \ni \varphi \mapsto |\varphi|^p \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I do not see where the derivative comes into play... could you please run through the case $p=2$?

Comment: I have dealt with the case $p = 2$. Do you see the derivative now? The same argument works in arbitrary Hilbert spaces. For $p \ne 2$, you also have to write out the integrals.

Comment: sorry, but I first do not see the following step: $\|f-g\|_2^2 - \|f - g + t \, (g-v)\|_2^2
\\=
-2 \, t \, (f-g,g-v) - t^2 \, \|g-v\|^2$. and in the next step you mistake the inequality sign isn't it?

Comment: The first step is just the expansion of the Hilbert space norm. The inequality sign is right, there is a minus on the right-hand side of the previous inequality.

Comment: sorry for that. and where comes the last chain of inequalities from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52553/discussion-between-gerw-and-tubmaster).